# Adding script tag before the end of body tag(Not Working)

Tags: javascript, html

In the below Code,I have added the script tag before the end of the body tag.So from my understanding,I should get html content first,in this case the header tag and three paragraph tags.After that,I should get the alert box.But I am getting the opposite.Alert box is being displayed first before the html content.I am not able to understand why.Please help me on this.Thanks in advance :)

```
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Todo List</title>  

    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Todo List</h1>

    <p>new ---> Add A Todo</p>
    <p>list ---> List All Todos</p>
    <p>quit ----> Quit App</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">alert('h')</script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML page loads as it follows unless you use any define any importance. Here you are right but the situation is HTML shows for micro sec or even less which we can't see. Then the alert box shows up. For this reason, it seems different from the theory but you can call as an illusion.

Comment: But If the HTML parser parses the contents of the document in order,then I should be able to see the content right since the parser encounters the script tag at last?